# jquery cfml trigger('change') not working

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

What I need is a cfselect bound to a query that lists file types, a cfdiv that lists the saved files, and a button that scans an image to be saved as a pdf file with the name prefixed by the value of the input field.

Simple page.

```
<cfselect name="DocType" id="DocType" class="selectClass" query="qGetDocTypes" display="name" value="DocTypeID">
<input name="ScanDocument" id="ScanDocument" type="text" value="" class="ScanDocument">

<cfdiv id="handler_#docAreaID#" bind="url:#request.controlurl#documentHandler/?docareaID=#docareaID#&variableID=#variableID#&Fav=#attributes.Fav#&userid=#attributes.userid#&showform=1&ScannedDocument={ScanDocument@change}">




// remove blanks from text
ScanDoc1 = $('input.scandocument').val();
ScanDoc = ScanDoc1.replace(/\s/g, '');
<cfoutput>
ColdFusion.navigate('url:#request.controlurl#documentHandler/?docareaID=#docareaID#&variableID=#variableID#&Fav=#attributes.Fav#&userid=#attributes.userid#&showform=1&ScannedDocument='+ScanDoc);
</cfoutput>
```

The coldFusion.Navigate does NOT refresh the CFdiv, and it also trigger an event for onBrowseAway I use for the main form action.  I can simulate the div refresh by manually changing the value of the input but it will be hidden after I get this to work.

Comment: I don't think you need the @change in this part of your bind url - ScannedDocument={ScanDocument@change}

Comment: I tried using
`code`var ScanDoc = $('input.scandocument').val();              ColdFusion.navigate('url:#request.controlurl#documentHandler/?docareaID=#docareaID#&variableID=#variableID#&Fav=#attributes.Fav#&userid=#attributes.userid#&showform=1&ScannedDocument=+ScanDoc+');`code`

But it creates a loop of binding the cfdiv.

Comment: Please see the revised question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this by stating that I have not used the `ColdFusion.navigate` functionality before but according to the [documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS0ef8c004658c1089-6262c847120f1a3b244-7fd0.html) the function needs to be a link target.  It needs to be in the `href` portion of an `a` tag.  Look at the example on the documentation page that I referenced.  So try adding your code to an `a` tag like this:

```
<cfoutput>
<a href="javascript:ColdFusion.navigate('#request.controlurl#documentHandler/?docareaID=#docareaID#&variableID=#variableID#&Fav=#attributes.Fav#&userid=#attributes.userid#&showform=1&ScannedDocument='+ScanDoc,'handler_#docAreaID#');">click here</a>
</cfoutput>
```

Notice that I removed the `url:` text from your code.  That does not appear to be necessary.

It also appeared as though you are missing the `container` parameter for the function. The documentation states that if you are missing this parameter the link will be treated as a normal URL and the entire page will be refreshed. (Although your code was not a link?)

Also, I'm not sure if you can reference the ColdFusion variables in the URL of the function like you are.  Those are server-side and this function is client-side (javascript).  Like I said, I have never used this before but these are my thoughts after reading that documentation.

Comment: *Notice that I removed the `url:` text from your code* Sounds like that is the real issue. @user990016 - Just to clarify the above, `ColdFusion.navigate` can be called anywhere you can invoke a javascript function (not just from a link). Also, using CF variables in the URL that way *is* valid. Because they are wrapped in `cfoutput`, the variables are evaluated and converted to simple strings. Just keep in mind those strings won't change until the page is refreshed. (You may also need to escape special characters to avoid javascript errors).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @Leigh!  I tried to mention that I am not too familiar with the `ColdFusion.navigate` function.  ;)

Comment: True, you got the main problems ie extra `url:` and missing container `id`. The rest is just clarification for future readers :)

Comment: Yes, that did it.  I just had to figure out how to pass the container ID.  Works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input.ScanDocument').trigger('Change');
```

if I were to guess, I would say that the capital "C" is the problem. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: $('input.ScanDocument').trigger('change');
doesn't work either