# Why does cfdiv bind not trigger

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery cfml trigger(‘change’) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174288/jquery-cfml-triggerchange-not-working)

```
<input name="btnScan" type="button" id="btnScan" style="WIDTH: 120;HEIGHT: 30" onClick="return btnScan_onclick()" value="Scan"/>
<input name="ScanDocument" id="ScanDocument" type="text" value="{DocType}" class="ScanDocument">
<cfselect name="DocType" id="DocType" class="selectClass" query="qGetDocTypes" display="name" value="DocTypeID">

<cfdiv style="border:1" id="handler_#docAreaID#" bind="url:#request.controlurl#documentHandler/?ScannedDocument={ScanDocument}">

$(".ScanDocument").val('changed to trigger bind');
```

If I select a document type, the input field is changed to reflect it.  But the cfdiv bind is not triggered.

I can change the bind to {DocType} and the bind happens every time I select a different document type. But, I cannot simulate the bind from Javascript or Jquery so that after I upload a new file I can refresh the list that's in the cfdiv.

Comment: What does the file to which you are binding your cfdiv actually do?

Comment: The cfdiv lists files that have been uploaded to the server.